# CSS Transform - Element Scales BUT doesn't Translate

Tags: javascript, css, translate

I have a video element inserted on my index.html page:

```
<body>
    <video id="animation" autoplay loop>
        <source src="animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="animation.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <script>
        scaletranslate();
    </script>
</body>
```

In my CSS sheet I am positioning the video simply:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

And the Javascript's `scaletranslate()` function is:

```
document.getElementById("animation").style.transform = "translateX(250)";
```

The video does not move as it should, however, if I use this code:

```
document.getElementById("animation").style.transform = "scaleX(0.2)";
```

Then the video does get scaled.

Why is the element not being moved with the transform translate operation?

Comment: Does combining them not work? `document.getElementById("animation").style.transform = "translateX(250) scaleX(0.2)";`

Comment: https://jsbin.com/jedacuyime/edit?html,css,js,console,output
You need to add a unit "px" to the translateX prop, like translateX(250px)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the pixel unit:

```
translateX(250px)
```

Comment: The more I learn about programming the more I realise its always something as trivial as this! 

Thank you, I shall accept your answer as soon as I am able to :)